# Handling uncaught exceptions in unaccessible Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I'm using `JavaSoundAudioIO` in my project, which starts up a thread of its own. If it deems the chosen audio mixer unfit, it throws an `UnsupportedArgumentException`, which will then crash the program. How can I catch this Exception? I can't really attach an exception handler directly to that thread, as I don't have a reference to it. I tried using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` from my main-thread, but that doesn't seem to do anything for the JavaSound-thread.

Comment: Could you show the exact stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: Also, could you show the line of code in which you use `JavaSoundAudioIO` (which causes that thread to be started behind your back) as well as your attempt at using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Comment: See my answer below, it was actually an issue with the Eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the Eclipse debugger was catching the exception and stopping execution before it could get to the exception handler.. Deactivated this behaviour in *Preferences>Java>Debug* and `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` works as intended.